# ASP.NET MVC Attribute routing parameter issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following code

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    [Route("/Books/{id?}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I try to enter the parameter it is (as it seems) considered as controller's action so I keep getting this exception.

[image: exception]

I need somebody to explain what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Your id is "sfawdas". With View("sfawdas"), it redirects to "sfawdas" view which doesn't exist as the screenshot shown. While there is something wrong that you define id is a nullable integer type in Route attribute, but the `id` parameter is a string type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass some parameter to a view as a string you can make this like below:

```cs
public class BooksController : Controller
{
    [Route("/Books/{id?}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            id = "default_value";
        return View((object)id);
    }
}
```

If the `string` type is passing to the `View()` call without casting to `object` it will be interpreted as a view name.

And the view model data should be declared as

```
@model string;
<h2>@Model</h2>
```

Comment: Is it the most efficient way to do such thing?

Comment: @JackFord: Yeap. Just take to account that when data model is `string` type it must be explicitly converted to the `object` type before passing to the strongly typed view.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the route as given below -

[Route("Books", Name = "id")]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).